# Read Write file in next js api

Tags: api, next.js, filesystems, writefile, nextjs-rewrites

I want to Write a example.txt file in a __dirname + "/testfolder/example.txt" but next js build version not allow to write. so how can I solve this problem ?

When I try to Write any file the it's log
`Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, Write`